# Why is my js function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Background**
I have a form that once submitted displays a bootbox dialog. If yes is selected on the form then the form detailed are posted.

**Problem**

Once yes has been clicked on on the dialog i would like a div to appear saying "thank you bla la"

**My solution**

I've added the div and hidden in using CSS

```
.fConfirm 
{
display:hidden;
}
```

then in my js once the form as submitted i've tried to change the CSS properties by adding this line

```
$('.fConfirm').css({display:inline-block; height: 680px; width:940px;});
```

This line of code however kills the whole function and stops the dialog from appearing?

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

> "fConfirm" Div

```
<div class="fConfirm">
          <h2>Thank you</h2>
          <p>Columbus Car Finder Group will now start looking for your perfect car and will contact you by one of the contact methods you have given us. If you have any questions or would like to change anything about your search feel free to either call or send us an email. </p>
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
 $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
            var currentForm = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {

                if (result) {

                    console.log("before display");
                         currentForm.submit();

                    $('.fConfirm').css({display:inline-block; height: 680px; width:940px; background: rgb(192, 192, 192);  background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5));



                    console.log("after display");

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Could it be the lack of quotes everywhere ?

Comment: Use selector `$('.fConfirm')` instead of $('.confirm'). Your div has class `fConfirm`.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Sorry no that was me making a change last min then not changing it properly on her. Edited question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object properties are separated via a comma, not semi-colon. Also, be sure to quote the properties value for `display` -- it is currently trying to subtract variable `block` from variable `inline`:

```
$('.FConfirm').css({
    display:"inline-block", 
    height: 680, 
    width: 940
});
```

Comment: As you noticed when editing, the problem is not the `px` or lack thereof, but the lack of quotes around values that was causing the browser to think OP was trying to subtract the value of `block` from the value of `inline` - neither of which exist.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol -- Yup, thanks for the clarification as well. Updated the answer.

Comment: IT was that indeed @tymeJV, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using .addClass in this situation:

Hide class initially:

```
.fConfirm {
    display: none;
}
```

Create a class to be added when you want to show:

```
.my_class {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 680px;
    width:940px;
}
```

Use jQuery to fire:

```
$('.fConfirm').addClass('my_class');
```

The reason this is ideal is because it keeps your CSS separate from your JS, which will prove beneficial over time. If you're only using this class with JS, it would be OK to prepend the class with "js" (i.e. ".js-my_class")

Comment: I need the class hidden until form is submitted. Thus why i have chosen to create class like you have done, but then change the CSS instead of adding it. Or am i misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: .fConfirm will still be hidden via your original post's CSS. The new class "my_class" will only be added when the jQuery above fires. I'll edit my answer to explain better.

Comment: Ahh i see, it's alway best to keep the CSS seperate from the HTML. I will change my implementation but the answer by @tymeJV answer my actual question. Thank you for showing me this better way of doing what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap values in quotes, otherwise JS will think they are variables:

```
$('.fConfirm').css({display:'inline-block', height: '680px', width:'940px'});
```

Also, note that your div's class is actually `fConfirm`, neither `FConfirm`, nor `confirm`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however wrap all the values is not necessary in this occasion. And thanks for the head up on the typos, changed my code last minute and didn't update my question properly.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function is just a way of intercepting the 'submit' event that is triggered when someone submits a form in whatever way.

The way i think of it is: "ok, we have this form called X and then, when someone triggers the submit of this form, don't act as it would normally do (lets prevent the default) and perform something different".

What you're doing is ok when talking about handling the submit event but you're calling `.submit()` at the end, which will then do what you don't want - perform the submit and then "kill the method".

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/knLkw/

**tl;dr**: don't call `.submit` later, but perform something async.

Comment: Ciosta, You are correct in what you are saying, i'm yet to add the the ajax.post() to tell it what to do once prevented default. I'm experimenting with different implementation of submitting a form at the moment.

Comment: I do see what you mean though as soon as the form is submitted it posts the data, refreshing the page thus undoing the change of CSS style.